# Tracking how long a viewer has viewed a certain video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, video.js

I am trying to track how long a viewer has viewed a certain video and I'm a bit confused as to what some of the media events do in [**React JS**](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

- When a video is skipped to a later part of the video and stops for a bit does it call `onPause` without actually needing to press the pause button?
- Also I am confused as to what `onTimeUpdate` does.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the HTML Audio/Video Event Listeners reference here:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp

You'll probably need the '[**readystate**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_readystate.asp)' property :

> Represents the ready state of the audio/video element:
>
> 0 = HAVE_NOTHING - no information whether or not the audio/video is
> ready
>
> 1 = HAVE_METADATA - metadata for the audio/video is ready
>
> 2 = HAVE_CURRENT_DATA - data for the current playback position is
> available, but not enough data to play next frame/millisecond
>
> 3 = HAVE_FUTURE_DATA - data for the current and at least the next
> frame is available
>
> 4 = HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA - enough data available to start playing

So, I would imagine you use a counter on a setTimeout to count how long the video has been played for:

```
var counter = 0;
var timer = setTimeout(function() { 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
    var state = vid.readystate;
    if( state != 0 ) counter++;
    console.log( counter + " seconds its been played" );
} , 1000 );
```